# Look for Resources in another Module from XML File - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

My project as multiple modules. Inherently, there will be resources that will be used across multiple modules. Let's call this resource logo_image.png

Currently, within the res folder of each module, there exists a copy of logo_image.png. This can be a problem as it can eat up a lot of space.

What I would like to do is to create a Common module, which stores all resources used across the project, and have all references point to a resource in that Common module. Is something like this possible? Here is my attempt at it (that fails)

#### activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@common/drawable/logo_image" />   <-- "Unknown reference
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a module in your project called `assets` or any other name you want. Then in each module that requires access to common resources, include that module as a dependency, in the module `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(':assets')
```

You would then access the assets like you would if they were defined locally in each module.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_image" />
```

Comment: Sometimes Android Studio doesn't see drawable file you have added recently. In that case run "Sync project with Gradle files" - it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use module to keep common resources, just add this plugin to build.gradle file of this module like this

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.library'
}
```

or replace com.android.application if it already defined there